# How do I respond to a POST from an iPhone app in PHP?

Tags: php, iphone, http

I have Objective C code creating an NSUrlConnection as follows:

```
//prepar request
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ctruman.info/post.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    //set headers
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/xml"];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    //create the body
    NSString *formData = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@  %@", username.text, password.text];

    NSData *postData = [[NSString stringWithString:formData] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //post
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    //get response
    NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;  
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];  
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];  
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
    if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);
     }
```

Then I have a php script that is supposed to read my POST variables that are being sent:

```
<?php
print('<pre>');
print_r($_POST);
print('</pre>');
?>
```

When I execute this, NSLog spits out the following:

```
Array
    (
    )
```

Why is it not printing out my post variables?  Am I making the POST request incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it looks to me, PHP is trying to read your POST submission as if it were a properly formatted PHP POST payload. Instead, you're setting the content-type to XML content -- which probably confuses the heck out of PHP. It's looking for encoded variables, and finding XML.

You've got 2 options:

1. Read in the XML and parse it yourself using PHP:
   $xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
   an example for reading input is here: http://www.codediesel.com/php/reading-raw-post-data-in-php/
   then you can parse it with PHP's xml support: http://us.php.net/xml
2. Recode your objective-C to just send normal POST parameters up to the server. I use the ASIHTTPRequest libraries and it's easy. http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 1):

The following code is working properly.

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *name = @"Anne"; // encode this
NSString *pass = @"p4ssw0rd"; // encode this
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&name=%@&pass=%@",name,pass];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://localhost/post.php"]]; 
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",resultString);
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

?>
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [name] => Anne
    [pass] => p4ssw0rd
)
```

**Alternative**

Checkout ASIHTTPRequest:
http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: This worked great, thank you!  The error was with my content-type and making the request string a UTF8String.