# Sending mail in background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am developing an iphone application in which i have to send a mail on custom button click and in background also it should not have user iteraction with mfmailcomposer view i.e, i dont have to show the view.

Please suggest me solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`The easiest solution for this problem is`,

You need to create your own webservice. Pass all the details to your webservice and accordingly send email.

Details to be passed on webservice would be to/cc/bcc/subject/body etc.

Comment: Can i send mail  using mfmailcomposer without showing its view Also suggest me with some code to send mail using webservices

Comment: If you use MFMailComposer than there will (must) be user interaction according to current SDK. If you don't want to have user interaction than as I said you need to create webservice and process accordingly.

Comment: The second solution is to implement your own SMTP client, and ask your user for their email address. That you can't send emails without the user knowing is by design. Apple (and their users) does not want apps that are spamming the internet with unsolicited emails.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Agreed. Updated Answer! But writing code for that SMTP client will not be too much time consuming against writing single webservice call ?

Comment: Please suggest some code to send mail using webservices in background

Comment: You can have one PHP Page which will accept all the parameters as post and from there send email. You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084365/how-do-i-respond-to-a-post-from-an-iphone-app-in-php this answer for reference.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using SKSMTPMessage:

http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/

You won't be able to use the user's email accounts unless you ask them to provide credentials, but I've used this a few times where the sender address is not important.

Comment: I am using the same link and implement it but i am getting the error login/password invalid in my console. Do you suggest some good line of code.